# How to allow python file to export specific functions that can be imported later?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have 2 functions and one global variable in a python file. How do I allow to export only one function?

```
g = 47
def A():
    print('a')

def B():
    print('b')
```

Suppose the above file is named as try.py. **I want to restrict all imports from try module except function A.**

Comment: prefix your private function name with an underscore that marks them as private (just a practice), there is no way to prevent it from importing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `__all__`:

```py
__all__ = ["stuff", "to", "export"]

<your code>
```

Not that if something undefined is in `__all__`, AttributeError is raised.

Comment: Note that `__all__` doesn't *prevent* the import of anything…